# PowerPivot for Excel 2013 KPI icons won't change and don't always appear

Tags: excel, powerpivot, kpi

I'm using Excel 2013 64-bit with PowerPivot, and am having a couple of issues with KPIs (and I'm [not alone](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/8bff2db6-5a3f-42ab-a7d3-d3b15a8f4d94/powerpivot-in-excel-2013-kpi-status-icons)).

I'm adding a KPI:

[image]

As you can see, I've chosen a non-default icon set.  Here's what you then see initially:

[image]

OK, I know the solution to this (and am sharing it here just in case it helps anyone else) - just untick the **Status** column, then re-tick it to redisplay it.  This seems to solve the problem (which didn't happen in PowerPivot for Excel 2010).

However, I then get this:

[image]

Definitely not the icons I asked for.  It seems that whatever icon set you choose, you always get the default ones.  Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: PS Why on earth did they rename measures to calculated fields?  Everyone will now confuse these with calculated columns ...

Comment: I suspect the rename was to help those familiar with calculated fields in Pivot tables make the jump to PowerPivot. I don't agree with it, but that's my suspicion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem. Seems to be a bug.

Steps for workaround:

1. Format a cell correctly on a separate worksheet using conditional formatting, select the cell.
2. Double click Format Painter under "Home Tab"
3. Format one of the status cells in the column.
4. Go to Conditional Formatting -> Manage rules -> Edit rule and choose: All cells showing "Your column Status" values.